# Firebird NET Provider and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, firebird

I've installed Firebird NETProvider and DDEXProvider on Windows 8 Enterprise (64-bit) with Visual Studio 2012 Premium successfully: I added a connection in Server Explorer and was able to see the database-objects.
However, when I install other extensions (Web Essentials, Power Tools, Resharper) I loose my previously saved connection and I'm unable to re-create it, because the Firebird NETProvider is no longer available. The same result after installing Windows updates (KB2781514), concerning a fix for VS2012.
Re-installing the NETProvider and DDEXProvider causes problems in the VS-configuration (double entries of dataproviders, etc.).

I'm unsure in using the Firebird NETProvider in a project with legacy Firebird-database) , because it seems to be unstable in VS2012.
Hopefully someone can help me.

Many thanks in advance

Dirk Schelfaut

Comment: File a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET or send a mail to the Firebird .NET provider mailinglist (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ for details).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems after installing VS 2012 SDK. Solution: Click the Advanced button in the installer and verify whether the correct combination of VS and OS is checked. With my installation, VS 2012 (64 bit OS) was checked, but I had W7 32 bit... You also may have to check the machine.config file. After re-installing, I had several duplicate entries for the Firebird data provider. Regards, Ulli.